# Building a MTB choosing a frame

Tags: frames

I am thinking about building a mountain bike, a trail hardtail with mabye 130 to 140mm fork up front.
Any suggestions on what to look for in getting the right frame?

Comment: That's a bit of a broad question, and also note that specific product recommendations are off topic.   Do read the [tour] to learn more about how the site works.   Can you use [edit] to refine this to something more specific, like "why would I pick a frame with boost rear spacing over something more common?" and post other questions separately.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will just leave it then and next time be more specific